# twitter bootstrap alert not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I want an alert box to show upon load. It doesn't. Here is the jsfiddle. What is wrong? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/4XZMb/1207/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <p>Fork this fiddle to test your Bootstrap stuff.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html" target="_blank">
                Learn more about Bootstrap
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
<div id="CanUseIPhoneAppPrompt" title="Please use the iPhone App." class="alert fade">    
      please try our iphone app                                      
</div>
```

and the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#CanUseIPhoneAppPrompt").alert();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked here, just removing the class `fade` on `div#CanUseIPhoneAppPrompt`